# Excel: Conditional formatting more (text) instances inside column or whole row

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, excel-2016

I have one workbook with more sheets (queries) inside, which are updated regularly. 
Among the columns there is a specific one (for groups) where there are many instances in **Column D (Vargrouptext)** as it is shown on the picture. You can see it is repetitive, and it has many of those options. Is there a quicker way to somehow "group" them by color or format them, but not that I go manually one per one, to select column and then manually to do? Is there a way to apply that conditional format on a whole row??

for example:

```
CPS101  CSP MODEL

CPS102 CSP MODEL

CPS103 CSP MODEL
```

To have whole row (Column A to D) formatted into some color, but to apply that on all instances from Vargrouptex with different color per instance?

For example I can apply this format painter or copy cond.format to make a bit quicker but I still have to click X times.

[image]

Comment: What sort of color scheme? Alternating, 3 colors, or just a random color one after the other?

Comment: @BigBen  Yeah, random color...just so they differ between "instances"...

Comment: Then you'll need VBA for this.

Comment: @BigBen Damn... :/  wanted to avoid it, just functions.

Comment: If you have a set number of pre-chosen colors, you can do it with conditional formatting. Otherwise if it's random colors,  you're restricted to VBA.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

- Select the whole range - A1:D88
- Conditional Formatting
- Mange Rules
- Use a formula to determine which cells to format
- Formula: `$D1=CSP Model"`
- Format - Fill - Select the color you want
- OK
- OK
- Apply

Repeat for every group

Results:

[image]

Comment: This seems to be work, and it can be auto updated any time new item is loaded.  Little bit of work but okay I got the point! Thx